# Two errors on error log when trying to use ZF2 on CentOS with PHP 5.3.24

Tags: centos, php, zend

I am trying to use zend framework 2, i follow these instructions on centos6 via ssh.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

and when trying to start my website up, it gives an error, i go to the error log and i get this.

```
[Sun Jun 30 16:02:17 2013] [error] [client 109.217.190.75] SoftException in Application.cpp:357: UID of script "/home/mydomain/public_html/public/index.php" is smaller than min_uid
[Sun Jun 30 16:02:17 2013] [error] [client 109.217.190.75] Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

What do they mean, how I fix them?

PHP 5.3.24

Comment: php version? zend version?

Comment: zend version2 like it states in the question. PHP 5.3.24

Comment: use `Zend Server CE 6.1` http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/release-notes or use `php 5.2`

Comment: I dont want to use zend server, I already have an awesome centos one. Do you think reverting to 5.2 would fix this though? I would be missing out on 5.3 which would suck.

Comment: Also, it really really doesnt make sense what you say about switching back because one the key promoted things about ZF2 is that they utilise php3?

Comment: I was wrong. But historically, the problem persists. When a new version of php 5.3, all products except Zend Server refused to work properly with this version. Yes, ZF2 done under php 5.3 here is my main mistake. As is happening now with version 5.4. If you need speed, use php 5.3.3 or higher - FastCGI. Maybe your question will clear up here: http://www.flynsarmy.com/2011/10/cpanel-softexception-uid-is-smaller-than-min_uid/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711085/uid-of-script-home-public-html-index-php-is-smaller-than-min-uid

Comment: LEGEND. write as answer please